# HTML5 Canvas: Draw lines from a centered DIV, connecting to other DIVs around it? (Spiderweb effect) Kinetic JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

My question is: How do I draw lines coming from a specific DIV, & having them connect to the other DIVs on the page? (Spiderweb effect)

So far, I got - **jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/audnB/3/

**But what I'm trying to do is...**
Have all the lines be coming from the mother div, as shown below:

[image]

Below is the code that I am currently using (the same as the one in my JsFiddle):
I am actually using `<a>` (links) for this & not DIVs, but you know what I mean...

```js
var lineCoords = new Array();
var stage;
var globalTimer = null;

$(window).resize(function() {
  clearTimeout(globalTimer);
  globalTimer = setTimeout(doneResize, 100);
});

function doneResize(){
 drawLines();
}

function drawLines(){
      lineCoords = new Array();
      $('div#container > a').each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('data-action-properties').length>0){
          var actionProperties = $.parseJSON($(this).attr('data-action-properties'));
        }
    var dx = $(this).css('left').replace('px','');
    var dy = $(this).css('top').replace('px','');
    var wd = ($(this).css('width').replace('px','') /2);
    var hi = ($(this).css('height').replace('px','') /2);

    var position = $(this).offset();

    lineCoords.push(parseInt(dx)+(wd));
    lineCoords.push(parseInt(dy)+(hi));
   }); 

      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
      var redLine = new Kinetic.Line({
      points: lineCoords,
      stroke: '#000',
      strokeWidth: 2,
      lineCap: 'round',
      lineJoin: 'round',
    dashArray: '0 30 0 30'
  });

      layer.add(redLine); 
      stage.add(layer);
  }

$(document).ready(function() {
   stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: "container",
        width: $('#container').width(),
        height: $(window).height()
      });
    setTimeout(drawLines,100);
  });

  $(window).resize(function(e){
stage.clear();
});

 function imageresize() {
   var contentwidth = $('body').width();
   if ((contentwidth) < '700'){
   $('.fluidimage').attr('src','little.jpg');
   } else {
   $('.fluidimage').attr('src','big.jpg');
    }
   }

   imageresize();// Triggers when document first loads

   $(window).bind("resize", function(){ // Adjusts image when browser resized
    imageresize();
   });
```

Thank you so much for your help, I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is close to what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/audnB/9/

basically similar to what Ani said.

All your lines need to be from your 0,1  to 2i,2i+1 so that the coordinates match. And in a loop.

```
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    for (var i=0; i<lineCoords.length / 2; i++){
         var redLine = new Kinetic.Line({
                 points: [lineCoords[0], lineCoords[1], lineCoords[2*i],lineCoords[2*i+1]],
                 stroke: '#000',
                 strokeWidth: 2,
                 lineCap: 'round',
                 lineJoin: 'round',
                 dashArray: '0 30 0 30'
         });
        layer.add(redLine); 
    };
    stage.add(layer);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Do you think there is any way to position the line to start from the center of the mother div? Right now, it just comes out from a corner. Not very visually ideal.

Comment: Nevermind the above question, I figured it out using `outerWidth` & `outerHeight`: http://jsfiddle.net/audnB/10/

Answer (score 1):

When you are declaring redLine as below

```
var redLine = new Kinetic.Line({
    points: lineCoords,
    stroke: '#000',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    lineCap: 'round',
    lineJoin: 'round',
    dashArray: '0 30 0 30'
    });
```

using `points: lineCoords`  essentially draw lines between consecutive points, so you have 2 options,
1. Starting from coordinates of point 2 onwards, after every point add coordinates of point 1 (Mother) assuming Mother is always the first.

```
points: [lineCoords[0],lineCoords[1],lineCoords[2],lineCoords[3],lineCoords[0],lineCoords[1],lineCoords[4],lineCoords[5]]
```

OR
2. make a for loop where you draw each line separately wherein assign point as: `point: [lineCoords[0],lineCoords[1],lineCoords[2*i],lineCoords[2*i+1]]`, essentially the start and end point of the line where `i = 1,2`